# Centralized package management for RPM based distro

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

We have about 6 servers under Linux CentOS.

And I want to have possibility to view (best will be some web-interface, but console-only useful too) outdated packages, which can be updated and have all this information in one place, without necessity to run `yum check-update` or read emails from `yum-updatesd` for every box.

If this will can directly run this updates - this will be ideal.

And may be - also have possibility to install new / remove old software from one place.

Comment: Look at Puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-enterprise), though it might be a bit overkill for "only" 6 servers.

Comment: Thanks, @M_dk. But as I remember - Puppet can't check && run updates. Or - can?

Comment: If you dont want to define a bunch of packages you can also run commands with something like http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/exec-a-command-in-a-manifest.html but again, this might be overkill because of the initial setup

Comment: Another way could be to set up your own local repository and set the clients to autoupdate using that. You then just control the versioning by controlling what packages are in the repo

Comment: @M_dk autoupdate - you mean `yum -y update` in cron?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just update your servers automatically, which is remarkably safe under CentOS 4/5/6/7 unless you've done really bad things.

Just do this:

```
yum install -y yum-cron
sysconfig yum-cron on
service yum-cron start
```

You're done.

If you want to just check what's available, and not install anything, do

```
yum upgrade
```

and hit N when you have the option.  It'll show you what you have for potential updates, and you can either install each one separately (it'll install dependencies for you) or not.

There are larger solutions - spacewalk, etc - but for SIX SERVERS, you're fine as-is.

I recommend, ultimately, for DEV servers you have a mix of updated and stale (matching PROD), that TEST servers are all fully updated, and that the PROD servers you update only to match the TEST ones when you promote software. It's nore required - it's enterprise linux, and incompatibilities are always from junky third-party repositories - but to appease the pointy-hairs or at least initially you may want to tread carefully.

I've run enterprise linux in production and, for 14 years now my prod boxes automatically update the repositories I trust.  Nightly.  Automatically.  No issues in those 14 years (except an smb.conf, but that was our own fault because puppet/chef was hand-writing the file instead of using authconfig like intelligent admins).  You can get to where you can update without fear, and you won't get insidiously updated to windows10 when you're not looking; but maybe go carefully now.